# Restricting Java based Web Server TLS protocols for inspection by Wireshark

Tags: java, android, ssl, playframework, wireshark

I am using a Java based Web Server ( PlayFramework 2.2 FWIW - see the [very good write up on TLS](http://tersesystems.com/2014/01/13/fixing-the-most-dangerous-code-in-the-world/) ), and I want to debug the SSL communication for various devices, eg: Android, to see exactly what is happening on the wire as far as TLS goes. For this I can use [Wireshark to decrypt the SSL layer](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL). This works if the server does not create an Ephemeral key, as [explained nicely by Steven Iveson](http://packetpushers.net/using-wireshark-to-decode-ssltls-packets/):

> Important: Ensure the use of a Diffie-Hellman Ephemeral (DHE/EDH) or
>   RSA Ephemeral cipher suite is not negotiated between the two hosts.
>   This is indicated by the use of a ServerKeyExchange message. There is
>   no way to decrypt data where ephemeral ciphers are used.

The [Java Secure Sockets Extension Reference Guide section on how to Disable Algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#DisabledAlgorithms) points to the `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms` property which I have tried setting directly in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file to

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DH, ECDH, EDCHE, DiffieHellman
```

I tried using some of the [Java™ Cryptography Architecture
Standard Algorithm Name Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html) as an attempt to select one of those strings, but I have been selecting a bit in the wild.

I tried setting it also using it in code to

```
java.security.Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","ECDH, ECDHE, ECDHE_RSA, DiffieHellman")
```

but that does not seem to stop the  the appearance of the `ServerKeyExchange` messages, as shown in the screenshot of Wireshark 1.11.2 on OSX: [image: screenshot of Wireshark 1.11.2 on OSX] . And indeed I don't seem to be able to decrypt the stream.

Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was close. The answer seems to be to set the security property as follows:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DHE, ECDHE
```

(I came on that after reading the hot-off-the-press blog post: [JDK 8 will use TLS 1.2 as default](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_will_use_tls)).

Once that is set on the server, an https connection captured by Wireshark no longer shows the `Server Key Exchange`  message.

[image: Wireshark on OSX showing a TLS 1.2 communication without perfect forward secrecy key negotiation]

It is then possible to decrypt content that went over the wire as shown by this image

[image: picture of unencrypted communication]

I hope this will be useful when trying to analyse what Android cell phones are receiving over the wire.

Comment: If it helps, the list of strings is defined in [SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/sun/security/ssl/SSLAlgorithmConstraints.java#265)

Comment: if the java client script is being run from a windows machine, can this be disabled there as well and how exactly? The server is an apache server and the packets were too found not able to decrypt.

Comment: I figured out how to do this on Windows but just wanted to verify that this setting will ensure the client script that runs will not use the algorithm encryption in its httpwebrequests?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but try doing it inside a privileged block:

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(
  new PrivilegedExceptionAction[Unit]() {
     java.security.Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms","ECDH, ECDHE, ECDHE_RSA, DiffieHellman")

  }
)
```

Comment: In order to remove any doubt about whether I was setting the Security property correctly, I set it directly in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` file that is part of the JRE. In order to remove all doubts I added   `println("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=" + java.security.Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms")) `
to my code and it printed out `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=DiffieHellman, ECMQV, ECDH, EDCHE, DH` to my console. ( That's the latest set of strings I tried ). I'll get back to your point when I solve the problem and get to programmatic attemps to set the property